# Pass By validation in Model

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a model with annotation REQUIRED on some fields but in some cases i want to pass by this validation when i use the command below.

```
"validation.valid(object);".
```

Can i do that? How?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove the `@Required` annotation from the class and validate the fields somewhere else, for example in your controller method, as in:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

public static void method(
        @Required value) {
          ....
    }
}
```